# Laravel validation only allow one value for each field

Tags: validation, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I currently have a validation for sortField but I checked this accepts

/api/request?sortField='date'&sortField='time'

and I want it to only accept one value for the sortField so the above request should fail and throw an error. This can be nullable also.

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
  'sortField' => 'string',
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you need to as custom validation for one word
- you can check by following link :

https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/laravel-custom-validation-rule-max-word-count/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).